# cannot destructure property 'getstate' of '_ref' as it is undefined (asyncThunk)

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk, getstate

```
export const addTeamReview = createAsyncThunk(
  "team/addTeamReview",
  async (teamId, comment, { getState }) => {
    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    try {
      await axios.post(`/api/teams/${teamId}/review`, comment, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);
```

In this code, I cannot place `{getState}` as 2nd parameter.I dont know what to do when when we have more than one parameter

I tried putting getState in 2nd and comment object in third..but its not working.
Also, i tried passing both teamId and comment in one object..that too isn't working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send multiple parameters to your asyncThunk, put them in an object.
You can read more about the asyncThunk parameters [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#parameters)

I'll highlight the important part for you here

> arg: a single value, containing the first parameter that was passed to the thunk action creator when it was dispatched. This is useful for passing in values like item IDs that may be needed as part of the request. If you need to pass in multiple values, pass them together in an object when you dispatch the thunk, like dispatch(fetchUsers({status: 'active', sortBy: 'name'}))